# chez scheme special lambda

Tags: lambda, scheme, apply

```
(lambda (head . rest)
     (...))
```

I encountered this code on the net when trying to learn some scheme, but I couldn't find any useful explanation.

What is the meaning of this? Is it some kind of pattern matching as in ML?
(Btw they apply this lambda to only one argument!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this procedure:

```
(lambda (arg . args)
     (...))
```

The syntax indicates that the `lambda` form is expecting one mandatory argument bound to the name `arg` and a list with zero or more elements (a variable number of arguments) bound to the name `args`. This is an example of a [variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function).

The same syntax can be used for named procedures, noticing that any number of parameters can be specified as mandatory and after that the rest are considered optional; take a look at this example:

```
(define (test arg . args)
  (apply + arg args))

(test)        ; will cause an error, at least one argument is expected
(test 10)     ; returns 10
(test 10 4)   ; returns 14
(test 10 4 2) ; returns 16
```

Comment: You could write the function more simply as (define (test arg . args) (apply + arg args)).

Answer (score 2):

This is »dotted-tail notation«. It allows you to pass an abritrary number of arguments to a function. For an explanation consider [SICP, exercise 2.20](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-15.html#%_sec_2.2.1) (please scroll down).